# React KeyboardAvoidingView issue with SlidingUpPanel does not return to its original position after closing the keyboard

Tags: react-native, expo

I have the following Component:-

```
import { useEffect, useRef, useState } from "react";
import {
  KeyboardAvoidingView,
  Pressable,
  ScrollView,
  StyleSheet,
  TextInput,
  View,
} from "react-native";
import colors from "../config/colors";
import SlidingUpPanel from "rn-sliding-up-panel";
import Header from "../components/common/Header";
import Text from "../components/Text";
import PasswordIcon from "../assets/svg/Login/PasswordIcon";
import Separator from "../assets/svg/Login/Separator";
import Checkbox from "expo-checkbox";
import Button from "../components/common/Button";
import { useNavigation } from "@react-navigation/native";
import FaceID from "../assets/svg/QuickLogin/FaceID";
import InsrgramButton from "../assets/svg/QuickLogin/InsrgramButton";
import WhatsappButton from "../assets/svg/QuickLogin/WhatsappButton";
import XButton from "../assets/svg/QuickLogin/XButton";
import DefaultAvatar from "../assets/svg/QuickLogin/DefaultAvatar";
import * as LocalAuthentication from "expo-local-authentication";

const QuickLoginScreen = () => {
  const panelRef = useRef(null);
  const [isChecked, setChecked] = useState();
  const navigation = useNavigation();

  const draggableRange = {
    top: 320, // The fully open position (adjust the value as needed)
    bottom: 0, // The closed position (typically 0)
  };

  const handleFaceID = () => {
    LocalAuthentication.authenticateAsync({
      promptMessage: "تسجيل دخول لمرشحكم",
    })
      .then((r) => console.log(r))
      .catch((e) => console.log(e));
  };
  const handleLogin = () => {
    navigation.navigate("Home");
  };
  console.log(panelRef);
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Header title="تسجيل الدخول" />
      <View style={styles.welcomeTextContainer}>
        <View style={styles.avatarContainer}>
          <DefaultAvatar />
        </View>

        <Text size="14" style={{ marginTop: 16, marginBottom: 10 }} bold>
          أهلا بك
        </Text>
        <Text size="14" bold>
          هاشم عبدالله
        </Text>
      </View>
      <Pressable onPress={handleFaceID}>
        <FaceID />
      </Pressable>
      <View>
        <Pressable
          onPress={() => panelRef.current.show()}
          style={styles.passwordLoginContainer}
        >
          <Text size="12" style={styles.passwordLoginText} bold>
            أو قم بتسجيل الدخول باستخدام
          </Text>

          <Text size="12" style={{ color: colors.green, marginLeft: 4 }} bold>
            كلمة المرور
          </Text>
        </Pressable>
      </View>

      <View style={styles.socialLoginButtonsContainer}>
        <XButton />
        <InsrgramButton />
        <WhatsappButton />
      </View>
      <KeyboardAvoidingView
        behavior="height"
        style={{ flex: 1 }}
        keyboardVerticalOffset={Platform.OS === "ios" ? 0 : -500} // Adjust the offset as needed
      >
        <SlidingUpPanel
          ref={panelRef}
          draggableRange={draggableRange}
          showBackdrop={false}
          initialAnimatedValue={0} // Set the initial position to 0 (fully open)
          containerStyle={styles.panelContainer}
        >
          <ScrollView contentContainerStyle={styles.panel}>
            <View style={styles.panelButton} />
            <View style={styles.panelContents}>
              <Text size="13" style={styles.enterPasswordText}>
                ادخل كلمة السر
              </Text>
              <View style={styles.textInputContainer}>
                <PasswordIcon />
                <Text size="10" style={styles.inputLabel}>
                  Pass
                </Text>
                <Separator />
                <TextInput
                  style={styles.textInput}
                  secureTextEntry={!isChecked}
                />
              </View>
              <View style={styles.showPasswordContainer}>
                <Text size="12">اظهار كلمة المرور</Text>
                <Checkbox
                  style={styles.checkbox}
                  value={isChecked}
                  onValueChange={setChecked}
                  color={isChecked ? colors.green : undefined}
                />
              </View>
              <View style={styles.linksContainer}>
                <Text
                  size="12"
                  style={{ ...styles.textLinks, marginBottom: 12 }}
                >
                  إستعادة كلمة المرور ؟
                </Text>
                <Text size="12" style={styles.textLinks}>
                  إستعادة اسم المستخدم ؟
                </Text>
              </View>

              <Button
                title="تسجيل الدخول"
                style={{ marginTop: 24 }}
                onPress={handleLogin}
              />
            </View>
          </ScrollView>
        </SlidingUpPanel>
      </KeyboardAvoidingView>
    </View>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: "white",
  },
  welcomeTextContainer: {
    justifyContent: "center",
    alignItems: "center",
    marginTop: 86,
  },
  avatarContainer: {
    justifyContent: "center",
    alignItems: "center",
    height: 104,
    width: 104,
    borderColor: colors.green,
    borderWidth: 2,
    borderRadius: 70,
  },
  passwordLoginContainer: {
    flexDirection: "row",
    justifyContent: "center",
    marginTop: 25,
    height: 30,
  },
  passwordLoginText: {
    textAlign: "center",
  },
  socialLoginButtonsContainer: {
    flexDirection: "row-reverse",
    justifyContent: "center",
    alignItems: "center",
    marginTop: 63,
  },

  panelContainer: {
    position: "absolute",
    bottom: 0,
    left: 0,
    right: 0,
    zIndex: 10,
    shadowColor: "#000",
    shadowOffset: {
      width: 0,
      height: 6,
    },
    shadowOpacity: 0.37,
    shadowRadius: 7.49,
    elevation: 12,
  },
  panel: {
    backgroundColor: "white",
    alignItems: "center",
    height: 320,
    borderTopRightRadius: 10,
    borderTopLeftRadius: 10,
  },
  panelContents: {
    marginTop: 19,
  },
  panelButton: {
    backgroundColor: colors.lgray4,
    width: 47,
    height: 5,
    marginTop: 8,
    borderRadius: 10,
  },
  enterPasswordText: {
    textAlign: "center",
    marginBottom: 16.2,
    color: colors.lgray5,
  },
  textInputContainer: {
    flexDirection: "row-reverse",
    alignItems: "center",
    borderColor: colors.lightGreen,
    borderWidth: 1,
    height: 48,
    width: 327,
    borderRadius: 8,
    marginBottom: 12,
  },
  textInput: {
    textAlign: "left",
    height: "100%",
    width: 150,
    marginRight: 10.79,
  },
  inputLabel: {
    color: colors.lgray1,
    marginRight: 12,
    marginLeft: 12.21,
  },
  showPasswordContainer: {
    flexDirection: "row",
    marginBottom: 12,
  },
  checkbox: {
    marginLeft: "auto",
    borderRadius: 5,
  },
  linksContainer: {},
  textLinks: {
    color: colors.lightGreen,

    textAlign: "left",
  },
});

export default QuickLoginScreen;
```

When i show the panel using (panelRef.current.show()) its showing in perfect size, but when open a keyboard the panel moves up and does not return to its original position after closing the keyboard .

[image]

The code in [exposnack](https://snack.expo.dev/@q8root/app-panel-issue)

How can i make panel return to its original position after closing the keyboard ?

Answer (score 0):

Fixed by changing the layout manually without using (KeyboardAvoidingView) component:-

```
const [keyboardHeight, setKeyboardHeight] = useState(0);

  const onKeyboardDidShow = (e) => {
    console.log("hhhh", e.endCoordinates.height);
    setKeyboardHeight(e.endCoordinates.height);
  };

  const onKeyboardDidHide = () => {
    console.log("keyboard hide");
    setKeyboardHeight(0);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    const keyboardDidShowListener = Keyboard.addListener(
      "keyboardDidShow",
      onKeyboardDidShow
    );

    const keyboardDidHideListener = Keyboard.addListener(
      "keyboardDidHide",
      onKeyboardDidHide
    );

    return () => {
      keyboardDidShowListener.remove();
      keyboardDidHideListener.remove();
    };
  }, []);
<SlidingUpPanel
      ref={ref}
      draggableRange={{ top: 320 + keyboardHeight, bottom: 0 }}
      snappingPoints={[0, 320 + keyboardHeight]}
      showBackdrop={false}
      //initialAnimatedValue={0} // Set the initial position to 0 (fully open)
      containerStyle={styles.panelContainer}
      allowDragging={props.noDrag ? false : true}
    >
      <View style={styles.panel} onPress={() => console.log("ccc")}>
        <View style={styles.panelButton} />
        <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={() => Keyboard.dismiss()}>
          <View style={styles.panelContents}>{props.children}</View>
        </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
      </View>
    </SlidingUpPanel>
```